# There should be no space after '{' (babel/object-curly-spacing)

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, eslint

I'm using `shift + alt + f` for sorting my code in `vscode` but why I'm Getting This Error:?

**Error:**

```
[eslint] There should be no space after '{' (babel/object-curly-spacing)
```

**Code:**

```
 User.findOne({ _id: temp }, (obj) => {
```

After removing space before _id and after temp, I haven't any error But How Should I Fix in vscode for auto arrange?

Comment: So did you configure VSCode to use eslint for formatting?

Comment: I just instaled eslint and added `editor.tabSize": 2`, and `editor.detectIndentation": false`

Comment: You've told VS to use eslint to check your coding style, so it warns about style problems like this.

Comment: I want to use alt shift f with no problem, how to say vscode remove that space? , if that space is a problem, why vscode added that extra space?

Comment: Find the place where you can configure eslint options, and turn off `babel/object-curly-spacing` checks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In your VS Code settings, change `javascript.format.insertSpaceAfterOpeningAndBeforeClosingNonemptyBraces` to `false` so it won't add those spaces before and after `braces`.

See [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/javascript#_formatting) for more options related to formatting of Javascript code in VS.

Comment: @SedricHeidarizarei I couldn't find that setting on the linked documentation page, so I rejected the edit. I don't have any actual experience with VS. Why didn't you just keep your own answer?

Comment: My VS Code is V 1.19.2 and I have That in VS Code settings, and Solved with Braces { }, I used your awnser because you awnsered First.

Comment: In my case, I was looking for the opposite, In my empty arrow functions like () => {} the formatter was adding a space in between, changing insertSpaceAfterOpeningAndBeforeClosingEmptyBraces to false solved it.
Thank you!

Answer (score 6):

in eslint just add

```
rules:{
 "arraysInObjects": false,
}
```

or run

```
npm run lint -- --fix
```

Answer (score 5):

as described in the official site [eslint.org](https://eslint.org/docs/2.0.0/rules/object-curly-spacing)
just added the blow line in `.eslint.trc` file

```
"object-curly-spacing": [2, "always"]
```

Answer (score 2):

To prevent `vscode` from addin spaces when formatting your code.

Open `settings.json` and add the following lines

```
"typescript.format.insertSpaceAfterOpeningAndBeforeClosingNonemptyBraces": false,
"javascript.format.insertSpaceAfterOpeningAndBeforeClosingNonemptyBraces": false,
```

This make the fix on both javascript and typescript formatters